# Send notification to a pubsub topic after Dataproc job ends

Tags: google-cloud-functions, gcloud, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-dataproc

I have Dataproc workflow consisting of Hadoop/Pig/Spark jobs. I was to send a message to a Pub/Sub topic after the whole Dataproc job ends. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use [Eventarc](https://cloud.google.com/eventarc/docs). It has a lot of supported [Dataproc events](https://cloud.google.com/eventarc/docs/reference/supported-events#cloud-dataproc). Deploy code to it that uses the GCP pubsub client library to send a message.

Answer (score 1):

I believe cloud functions can also do the job, you can set it up to be triggered once your dataproc workflows are completed. Cloud functions can check workflow status and send your message to a subscribed pub/sub topic.

Adding some references which relate to your use case.

- [Trigger Dataproc serverless job using cloud composer](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Data-Analytics/Trigger-Dataproc-serverless-job-using-cloud-composer/m-p/631177)
- [Start DataProc job from Pub/Sub notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62524479/start-dataproc-job-from-pub-sub-notification?rq=2)
- [How can I run create Dataproc cluster, run job, delete cluster from Cloud Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50359270/how-can-i-run-create-dataproc-cluster-run-job-delete-cluster-from-cloud-functi)